# JQMIGRATE: jQuery( '#' ) is not a valid selector, jquery 3.5.1, jqmigrate 3.3.2

Tags: jquery, jqmigrate

I am upgrading jquery from 1.10 to 3.5 but facing this warning. Same line of code is being used in various places in script but it is only giving error in just one place.

**Script Code:**
var initializeSettings = $("#" + containerId).data("mysettings-" + containerId);

Warning:
**JQMIGRATE: jQuery( '#' ) is not a valid selector.**

How to resolve this warning?

Comment: *how to resolve this warning* - by giving it a valid selector.   Easiest is to check if `containerId` actually has a value

Comment: I checked it already, it has a value.

Comment: Well that's what the error is telling you.  Your next step is to provide an [mcve] - edit question and click `[<>]` to add a *working* snippet that **demonstrates the problem**.  Perhaps it's a different line?